# Ignoring eslint error for moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am adding moment.js in my react app as an external resource like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

When I use `moment` in my code file where `eslint` is enabled then I am getting this eslint error: `'moment' is not defined(no-undef)`.

This is my .jsx file-

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    startDate: moment()
  }
}
...
```

My `eslintrc.yml` look like this:

```
extends:
- jquery
- airbnb

parser: babel-eslint

parserOptions:
  ecmaVersion: 6
  ecmaFeatures:
    experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
    jsx: true
  sourceType: "module"

env:
  browser: true
  node: true
  jquery: true
...
```

Comment: As you are using moment globally (bound to the window object) you can use window.moment in your modules. As an alternative, you can install moment by npm and use it as any other module in your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you use webpack.
    npm install moment --save
    import moment from moment;

Or you can disable linting by adding a comment after `moment()` in the same line. `// eslint-disable-line`

Answer (score 0):

If using is a hard requirement

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

But you can edit the `.eslintrc` file, you can tell `eslint` that you have made moment available in the global namespace, which is what your script tag is doing.

```
{
//...
    "env": {
        "moment": true
    }
//...
}
```

[Link to `eslint` environment docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)